# Where to find logs for "Low Disk Space"

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, disk-usage, log, syslog

After seeing the window popping up that shows

> Low disk space | The volume "Filesystem root" has only X MB disk space remaining.

Where can we find the log file that logs this low disk space warning?

If it is not logged by default, how can we log it so that we can record down some details like the timestamp of this event?

**Output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i disk`:**

```
Sep  5 09:10:11 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start timed out.
Sep  5 09:10:11 foo systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device.
Sep  5 09:10:11 foo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/4d64b496-3e08-497f-9e51-40db25c7710b.
Sep  5 09:10:11 foo systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep  5 09:10:11 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep  5 09:34:55 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start timed out.
Sep  5 09:34:55 foo systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device.
Sep  5 09:34:55 foo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/4d64b496-3e08-497f-9e51-40db25c7710b.
Sep  5 09:34:55 foo systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep  5 09:34:55 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep  5 10:03:12 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start timed out.
Sep  5 10:03:12 foo systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device.
Sep  5 10:03:12 foo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/4d64b496-3e08-497f-9e51-40db25c7710b.
Sep  5 10:03:12 foo systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep  5 10:03:12 foo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4d64b496\x2d3e08\x2d497f\x2d9e51\x2d40db25c7710b.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Comment: Is the goal just to monitor a computer's available storage space over time? 

Comment: Can you edit our question and post the result of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i disk` please?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: @matigo Yes, and the disk space available fluctuates wildly so I am trying to get an approximate timestamp of when it goes really low.

Comment: @N0rbert 14.04, 16.04, both using Mate desktop

Comment: @darth_epoxy Updated with the output you requested. The other `syslog*` files contains more of the same

Comment: 14.04 EOL, 16.04 EOL. What is your current system? Why do you show Unity on screenshot?

Comment: @N0rbert Ugh I got confused with another system, Mate is the correct desktop environment. I'm stuck on 14.04 and 16.04 for these machines due to a software being used that requires them

Comment: See my below answer. Just tested on 16.04 LTS MATE VM - log monitoring shows that this low-space warning is not logged. .

Comment: You may want to set up some sort of disk space monitoring that works independently of your desktop environment. Something as simple as a cronjob doing `df -k / | tail -n 1 | logger` every hour or even every minute may be enough.

Answer (score 2):

This dialog is [generated](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=disk+space+remaining&literal=1&perpkg=1) by desktop settings daemons. Depending on the flavor the list includes:

- `cinnamon-settings-daemon`
- `gnome-settings-daemon`
- `mate-settings-daemon` (your case, based on comments)
- `ukui-settings-daemon`

For MATE log monitoring shows that this low-space warning is not logged. You can check space distribution using MATE Disk Usage Analyzer (`mate-disk-usage-analyzer`) or via CLI - using `ncdu`. Then you can move/remove huge files in your home directory.

Cleaning old kernels, kernel headers and package cache may be useful - try commands below:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```